# Why should I add identifiers before struct? I can't see why, how to fix this?

Tags: c, unix, struct

This is the code in my .c file:
[image]

This is the error:
[image]

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: If you are posting here, you should post code atleast and give the exact description of what is the problem and error with current code.!

Comment: The actual problem is inside `list.h`, or in something above the fragment you showed. We need to see a _complete program_, as text, or we will not be able to help you. Please read and follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I reject the potential edit: we need code, not pretttier links.

Comment: To elaborate on what WeatherVane is saying, we want you to copy and paste your code, and the error messages, into the question box.  We do not want you to post screenshots, because then we have to retype everything in order to tinker with it.  Tinkering with the code you post is an important part of how we figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: You posted a _picture_ of text in a _text based_ system.  Lets think about that for a while...

Comment: Sorry I am new here in Stackoverflow, and I am just not very familiar about how to use it to ask questions, please don't be angry. QAQ

Comment: @WeatherVane : I agree, but it is not really for me to type all that stuff in, so I took the simplest solution by making the images he had posted visible because he has insufficient rep to do so himself.  Many first timers never return to this site because of the hard time they get from those with experience but little tolerance.  If he'd had any rep, he'd deserve a hard time.  I would ask him to replace the images at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: @Clifford a good point, but I have neither downvoted nor requested to close, out of intolerance: just to ask for textual code in the question - perhaps a little curt.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I have never found you to be anything other than helpful. The part about intolerance was a general one not intended to be aimed at you.  Sadly despite being engaged in the discussion La has chosen to ignore the request..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get an error message like

```
[file]:[line]:[column]: expected [punctuation] before [keyword]
```

the problem is usually with the code right *before* the line that the compiler is complaining about.  For instance, you will get an error like this when the previous declaration or statement was not ended correctly:

```
struct THING { }   // oops! forgot a semicolon on this line
struct OTHER { };  // compiler complains here, but the problem is up there
```

This is because the compiler doesn't "know" there is a problem until it processes the beginning of the second statement.

In C, to find the code "right before the line", you may have to look past or into preprocessor directives.  In your code snippet

```
#include "list.h"
#define true 1
#define false 0
struct NODE *head;
```

when the compiler is parsing `struct NODE ...`, the `#define` directives aren't there anymore, and `#include "list.h"` has been replaced with the contents of the file `list.h`.  So, probably the missing semicolon or whatever is inside `list.h`.

Without seeing your complete program, I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I get your what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler issues errors for the code it sees *after* preprocessing, so you have to consider what that code looks like *after* the included "list.h" has been expanded.

Whatever is at the end of that file is most likely the cause of the error - a missing semi-colon at the end of a struct definition for example.